# Is there a term for this type of equation? $y = \frac{2}{x^2+16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

> Is there a term for this type of equation?
> $$y = \frac{2}{x^2+16}$$

It has two vertical asymptotes. If the degree of the variable in the denominator is higher than the degree of the variable in the numerator there is one horizontal asymptote at $0$. So I gather the number $2$ does not count as having a degree hence this is not a rational expression. Is there a name for it?

Comment: Any function which can be written as $$\frac{\text{polynomial}}{\text{another polynomial}}$$ is called a *rational function*. NB the number $2$ is a polynomial. Does that help?

Comment: It is similar to what people call a Lorentzian (especially physicists)

Comment: $2=2x^0$ is a polynomial of degree $0$.

Comment: How are there two vertical asymptotes when the denominator is _never_ equal to zero?  Is your expression typed correctly?  $ \ \frac{2}{x^2 - 16} \ $ has two vertical asymptotes.

Comment: I made a mistake, there is only one asymptote, I was calling a vertex an asymptote.